# Safari web audio visualizer works with mp3 file but not with stream

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to stream audio and visualize it via canvas, however it appears to only work with a static file (mp3 in this case) when I need to get it to work with a continuous stream.

It looks as the bufferArray is full of zeros using getByteFrequencyData, or 128 using getByteTimeDomainData.

**Important Notes**

1. It is not an actual MP3 file the audio source is coming from but a buffer stream that is updated periodically, for proprietary reasons I can not share the actual URL, but it would look like this for example "http://somedomain/stream". The format MP3 is actually delivered in the headers.
2. Cannot use fetch or other XHR request as the URL needs to be sharable when it goes live.
3. Cannot change header format

Please see the following code snippets.

**Example files**
static mp3 file: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/481938/Find_My_Way_Home.mp3
stream endpoint: http://rfcmedia.streamguys1.com/MusicPulse.mp3

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn">Start</button>
<canvas id="canvas" style="background:black;width:512px;height:255px;"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = () => {
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
        const audio = new Audio()
        audio.autoplay = false
        audio.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
        audio.src = 'http://rfcmedia.streamguys1.com/MusicPulse.mp3'


        const player = document.getElementById('audio_player')
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
        const canvasCtx = canvas.getContext('2d')
        const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext ||
            window.webkitAudioContext)()
        const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser()
        analyser.connect(audioContext.destination)

        const audioSourceNode = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio)
        audioSourceNode.connect(analyser)

        const data = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount)

        const render = () => {
            analyser.getByteFrequencyData(data)

            canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            const center = canvas.height / 2
            let diff = 10
            let shape = {
                x: diff,
                y1: center,
                y2: center
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                let height = data[i] / 2

                if (height) {
                    shape.y1 = center - height
                    shape.y2 = center + height

                    const { x, y1, y2 } = shape

                    const lingrad = canvasCtx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 180)
                    lingrad.addColorStop(0, '#5d8db6')
                    lingrad.addColorStop(0.515, '#5d8db6')
                    lingrad.addColorStop(0.52, '#fff')
                    lingrad.addColorStop(0.53, '#fff')
                    lingrad.addColorStop(0.535, 'rgba(93, 141, 182, 0.6)')
                    lingrad.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(93, 141, 182, 0.6)')

                    canvasCtx.beginPath()
                    canvasCtx.moveTo(x, y1)
                    canvasCtx.quadraticCurveTo(x - diff, center, x, y2)
                    canvasCtx.moveTo(x, y1)
                    canvasCtx.quadraticCurveTo(x + diff, center, x, y2)
                    canvasCtx.closePath()
                    canvasCtx.fillStyle = lingrad
                    canvasCtx.fill()

                    shape.x = x + 8
                }
            }

            requestAnimationFrame(render)
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(render)
        audio.play()
    })
}
```

Comment: is MP3 required or could you use Ogg Opus or WebM Opus instead of MP3?

Comment: @AnthumChris MP3 is a requirement unfortunately

Comment: You can fill a bug report at https://bugs.webkit.org/enter_bug.cgi The problem is even before you try to analyse it: createMediaElementSource doesn't work.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using [Media Source Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API), which allows you to read and decode chunks of the file while it streams.  [This MSE MP3 tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/Media-Source-Extensions-for-Audio) may be useful too.  That tutorial references XHR, but you could also use fetch() with the streams API to play the audio

Comment: This will unfortunately not work (https://jsfiddle.net/fuz0ed4j/). The bug is that they don't support transferring the audio to the web audio context graph when the MediaElement points to a stream, so generating a new stream from that won't help.